# link excel objects from server to powerpoint

Tags: excel, server, office365, powerpoint, vba

Is there any way to paste objects from excel sheet located in server into my local ppt presentation ?

Both of them should be linked so that whenever the excel file in server changes,my presentation linked to that file also changes.

When I go to paste special options of my PowerPoint presentation there is no way to paste the server excel object as a linked one.

Anyone having any idea how can I do so?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

In order to Paste Special / Link, the data to be linked has to be on the clipboard. There's no way (or none that occurs to me) to put data on the clipboard of one PC from an app running on another PC/server.

However, you could create the link from a copy of the XL file on the local PC, then modify the linkpath to point to the same file on the server, assuming that the file's available to the PC via a UNC or mapped drive path.

There are several bits of example code on the PowerPoint FAQ page that I maintain:
Batch Search and Replace for Hyperlinks, OLE links, movie links and sound links
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm